# Get JSON text from a online server

Tags: javascript, html

Ive been working on a site and it has a JS script that runs every 15 seconds which will go to a Github raw text site and get the data off that but I noticed it can be rate-limited.

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function OnLaunch() {
    var i = 1
    while (i < 10) {
        const url = 'https://github.com/PS5Australia/stocktrackerau/blob/main/stock.json'
        var response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
            }
          }
        )
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(data => {
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            if (obj["AmazonDisc"] == "Out of Stock") {
                document.getElementById("amazondisc").innerHTML="Amazon | Out of Stock";
            }
            else if (obj["AmazonDisc"] == "In Stock") {
                document.getElementById("amazondisc").innerHTML="Amazon | In Stock";
            }
        });
        await sleep(15000);
    }
}
```

I have stock bots that will change the json, so is there another way of updating that json?

I am running on Azure but I can swap to AWS if need be.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the question. What's the problem you're having?

Comment: Why are you sleeping? Why is nothing returned from the last `then` (`response` will likely be undefined).

Comment: @evolutionxbox Because of the rate limit, probably.

Comment: You never increment `i`, so the `while` loop is infinite.

Comment: @Barmar yes I want it to loop, my code is still in beta I will make it stop when it updates text for stock.

Comment: It would be better if you didn't mix `await` with `.then()`. Just use `await` for everything.

Comment: @evolutionxbox im using a sleep as it does not need to spam the github to look.

Comment: @Barmar im am a python-dev so I'm learning js atm. I will do that

Comment: @Barmar the issue im having is that is this I run a ps5 stock bot. PS5s run out of stock within 1-3 mins. If I use the github azure takes 1-2 mins to update the site and the ps5s would be out of stock by then. I want to use a json so I can make js look for "In Stock" in a dict.

Comment: Btw, you can use `response.json()` instead and skip parsing it yourself.

Comment: I have no idea what any of that means or why it's relevant. JavaScript is JavaScript.

Comment: Is your question about fetching the JSON or updating the JSON file on Github? This code is just for fetching the JSON.

Comment: Why is it a JSON on Github in the first place? You have Azure hosting, right?

Comment: I need to fetch a JSON somewhere. I need to be able to update that JSON. Github has a rate limit and takes to long to update my site files. I need a way to access a JSON!

Comment: @ChrisG im using Static Web App so I can use my custom domain. It is based off github I think. It was the first option.

Comment: It sounds like what you need is a proper realtime database, like Google Firebase. Still, you need to clarify what exactly you're asking here. Surely it's not "Get JSON text from a online server" because your code already does that. Is it "how to modify a JSON on github?"

Comment: Maybe a database, ill get back to you soon!

Comment: @ChrisG what I am trying to do is have my js script go to a json file hosted somewhere. I need to be able to access that JSON to edit the data within a python bot. If you have any idea lmk!

Comment: Sorry, but I asked you to *clarify*. You need to tell us exactly what your JS is supposed to do / be able to do. "go to a JSON file" means nothing to me. "access that JSON to edit the data within a python bot" means nothing to me. Also, this sounds more like a massive [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/) so please make sure it isn't.

Comment: @ChrisG uhhh I did clarify "what I am trying to do is have my js script go to a json file hosted somewhere. I need to be able to access that JSON to edit the data within a python bot" I need to be able to have a json online that I can access with my site and my bot can access to update the dict.

Comment: So you basically want to store a bunch of information online, and you want to read and edit this information both from a python bot as well as a static website. Which means the main issue is to edit the information from client-side JS code, which means that you need something like firebase, unless you want to publish your github credentials and send them through a cors proxy.

Comment: From the description of Azure's Static Web App it sounds like they already have a storage solution you can use, so you need to ditch the whole "JSON on github" business and use actual mutable storage.

Comment: @ChrisG dont worry, https://jsonbin.io/ I get lots of requests can access on my site and can update with python.